# Pushing multiple variables into single function Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I've created a function that takes in a variable and returns the last value in the variables array. How do I push multiple variables arrays to go through the function? It works for var arr but not pzz?

```js
var arr = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
var pzz = ['jkl', 'lmn', 'opq'];
    
      
    function valueIn(v) {
        vLength = v.length;
    
        console.log(v[vLength-1]);
    
    }

    
valueIn(arr);
```

Comment: `[arr, pzz].forEach(valueIn)`

Comment: Thanks works great. Just out of interest is there a way to loop through the script to identify all the declared variables in the global scope?

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't have any variables in the global scope except for the built-in ones. If you want to iterate over a bunch of variables, then just assign them to an array in advance. `const myArrs = [arr, pzz];`

Comment: try this `valueIn([...arr,...pzz])`

Comment: @NS01 Especially, you shouldn’t have any unknown variable names. If you want dynamic names, use an object instead: `let obj = {arr, pzz}`, then get `obj.arr`, or use one of the [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor) methods to iterate through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the js Arguments object to access every argument sent. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

```js
var arr = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
var pzz = ['jkl', 'lmn', 'opq'];
    
function valueIn() {
   for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      v = arguments[i];
      console.log(v[v.length - 1]);
   }
}
   
valueIn(arr, pzz);
```

A second way to do this is to use the spread operator. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
var arr = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
var pzz = ['jkl', 'lmn', 'opq'];
    
function valueIn(...args) {
   for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      v = args[i];
      console.log(v[v.length - 1]);
   }
}
   
valueIn(arr, pzz);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code assumes your intent is to write to the console.
@CertainPerformance is correct to recommend to run a for each loop. However, I would recommend pushing the values to another array so you can run it as needed.

```js
var valueInArray = [];
var arr = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
var pzz = ['jkl', 'lmn', 'opq'];
valueInArray.push(arr, pzz);

function valueIn(v) {
  vLength = v.length;

  console.log(v[vLength - 1]);

}


valueInArray.forEach(function(el) {
  valueIn(el);
});
```

And in ES6

```js
var valueInArray = [];
var arr = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
var pzz = ['jkl', 'lmn', 'opq'];
valueInArray.push(arr, pzz);

function valueIn(v) {
  vLength = v.length;

  console.log(v[vLength - 1]);

}


valueInArray.forEach(el => (valueIn(el)));
```